# Is pip Thread Safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, pip

I have a build script (bash) utilizing python `pip` to fetch requirements from a remote and put it into a virtual env. This build script can be invoked by another script that will call it with any number of threads and different targets. This causes pip to be re-run for each invocation. It will try to check the same requirements for the same virtual env.

Will this be incompatible with `pip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2361), pip should be mostly thread safe, unless the repository state changes while updating.

Comment: What does "repository state" mean?

Comment: @BourgondAries Well say you install a package. For the first thread, the package version is 1.0, but then the package is updated, the the second thread sees version 1.1. This is extremely unlikely, but would probably break things if it happens.

Comment: Thread safety is binary. "Mostly thread safe" means _not_ thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

As this discussion is the first hit on google: pip should not be considered thread safe. Plus there is a bug in pip that might cause an exception when invoking pip from within a thread if you are not running `pip.main()` inside the thread that imported xthe pip package.

Running `pip.main()` is also not a supported API. The only recommended method is to invoke pip from `subprocess.Popen()` or similar.

More details here:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3889

Answer (score -1):

`pip` being run each time is a waste of bandwidth and resources.

In the virtualenv the installed packages stay installed. Hence you could set a flag or a file in the directory which stores a flag, on checking the flag you can execute `pip` or not. This is a much better solution.

Comment: Doesn't `wheel` take care of recognizing that?

Comment: I don't think so, whenever I've used pip with a requirements.txt file it checks manually for all the packages, it re-downloads the files first, then if it's already installed it exits. However the download occurs.

Comment: This does not answer my question btw. I need to know about thread safety.